# Laravel 5.3 Vue 2.0 getting database data to Vue

Tags: laravel-5.3, vuejs2

I am not sure if I am confused, is it true that I should leave the job of getting data from database for controller and processing the data for vue? Or is this the best practice or something?

Here I am trying to get the subcat from my subcategories table, not error on devtool but `subcats` is not being set. Please help or feel free to suggest a better practice. Thanks!

Item-sorting-list.vue

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <div v-show="isActive">
      <li v-for="subcat in subcats" class="list-group-item">
        <a name="" href="">{{subcategory.name}}</a>
      </li>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
  export default {
    props:[
    ],
    data(){
      return {
        subcats:[]
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      this.getAllSubcat()
    },
    methods: {
      getAllSubcat(){
        var vm = this;
        vm.$http.get('/getSubcat').then((response)=>{
          vm.subcats = response.data.data.subcat.data;
        });
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

SubcategoryController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Subcategory;

class SubcategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function getSubcat()
    {
      $subcat = Subcategory::Orderby('name')->get();
      $response = [
          'data' => [
              'subcat' => $subcat
          ]
      ];
      return response()->json($response);
    }
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/getSubcat', 'SubcategoryController@getSubcat');
```

Comment: Are you sure `response.data.data.subcat.data` has data you want?

Comment: @saurabh Thanks for your response. I did use response.data.data.item.data to successfully get the data from a controller which only differently called the database with $items = App\Product::where('something',someValue)->latest()->pagination     but im not sure what is the different since get() gives me an array of several objects right?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @saurabh that I double check and `response.data.data.subcat` should be the correct calling. paginate does read the data differently.